Как сделать вибрацию при касании элемента сайта на iOS
Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу реализовать вибрацию при касании элементов сайта для iPhone. Для android использую:
   const vibrate = () => {
    if ("vibrate" in navigator) {
      navigator.vibrate(100);
    }
  };

Не могу найти решение для iPhone. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался и смог решить.

Посмотрите принятый ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926591/navigator-vibrate-break-the-code-on-ios-browsers
